# android studio не могу запустить

Tags: android

не могу запустить android studio. после установки выскакивает это окно. что делать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5):

Перевожу: "Переменная среды `JAVA_HOME` (со значением `C:\Program
Files\Java\jdk\bin`) не указывает на верную установку JVM." В общем последний каталог в пути явно лишний, должно быть просто `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk`. Для редактирования этой переменной воспользуйтесь следующей инструкцией:

Найдите значок Мой компьютер и вызовите Свойства из контекстного меню, или просто откройте Мой компьютер и по пустому месту ПКМ – <kbd>Свойства</kbd>. Должен открыться просмотр сведений о вашем компьютере. Далее переходим на вкладку <kbd>Дополнительно</kbd>, и там в самом низу кнопка <kbd>Переменные среды</kbd>. Во второй таблице под названием Системные переменные ищем и выделяем переменную `JAVA_HOME` и жмем кнопку <kbd>Изменить</kbd>. Дальше думаю должно быть понятно.

И не забудьте убедиться что JDK у вас действительно установлен в C:\Program Files\Java\jdk

Comment: или вообще хоть куда то установлен :)

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, скачайте и установите JDK.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.